# jQuery UI slider and sortable incompatible in IE8

Tags: jquery-ui, cross-browser, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-slider

I have a jQuery UI slider wrapped in a sortable li. The html is like this:

```
<ul class="sortable">
   <li><div class="slider"></div></li>
   <li><div class="slider"></div></li>
</ul>
```

In IE8, when I drag the slider, the `li` will be dragged, too.
But I Chrome and FF, things are expected.

I think this has something to be with event propagation, I tried to add stopPropagation in the slider but it still does not work.

Any hint?

Comment: I made a quick [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WRS2u/) that works in IE8/9. Could you describe what behaviour you want that is different to the demo. Which version of jQueryUI are you using?